# How would I delete duplicate data from two tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-delete

My first table a has the columns ID, invdate and invnumber with VALUES:

```
(1, 01/10/13, 1)
(2, 02/10/13, 2)
(2, 02/10/13, 2)
(3, 03/10/13, 3)
(4, 04/10/13, 4)
(4, 05/10/13, 4)
```

My second table b has the columns ID, DATEOFBIRTH, lastname, firstname with VALUES:

```
(1, 19/06/1997, Fox, Migan)
(2, 30/07/1993, Todd, James)
(2, 30/07/1993, Todd, James)
(3, 1/08/1994, Xi, Ji)
(4, 2/07/1992, Fared, Bob)
(4, 2/07/1992, Fared, Bob)
```

How would I use the DELETE FROM () function to delete all duplicated rows in both tables? I think I should merge the tables somehow then delete the duplicated rows but not too sure.

As for the results,

```
SELECT * FROM a
```

should give:

```
(1, 01/10/13, 1)
(2, 02/10/13, 2)
(3, 03/10/13, 3)
(4, 04/10/13, 4)

SELECT * FROM B;
```

should give:

```
(1, 19/06/1997, Fox, Migan)
(2, 30/07/1993, Todd, James)
(3, 1/08/1994, Xi, Ji)
(4, 2/07/1992, Fared, Bob)
```

UPDATE (SOLUTION) :

DELETE FROM a WHERE rowid>(SELECT min(rowid) FROM b WHERE a.ID= b.ID);

Can someone explain this sql for me?

Comment: Edit your question and explain/show the results that you want.

Comment: You need only filter duplicates at `SELECT` or actually delete duplicate rows in table ?

Comment: yes, I need to use DELETE FROM( ... to actually remove  the duplicate rows from the table

Comment: `delete from` is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Below is example for your "b" table

taken from here http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_delete_duplicate_table_rows.htm

(You can do similar for your "a" table also)

```
  DELETE FROM 
  b  t1
  WHERE 
  t1.rowid > 
  ANY ( SELECT  t2.rowid FROM  b t2
       WHERE 
          t1.id = t2.id AND  t1.DATEOFBIRTH = t2.DATEOFBIRTH AND t1.lastname = t2.lastname AND  t1.firstname  = t2.firstname 
       );
```

Comment: says 0 rows deleted

Comment: Are your rows really duplicated?

Comment: Run query: `select  count(*) from b
group by  id, DATEOFBIRTH , lastname, firstname
order by count(*) desc`

Comment: And watch, what is first result from this query?

Comment: ohhhh thanks, i think only the rows in table a are duplicated